# Clean way to apply javascript object to multiple instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, oop

Really asking this to get a better understanding of object-oriented javascript and to uncover some best practices for this scenario. Let's say I have a javascript object, such as:

```
SideSlider = {
        rightArrow: '.controls i.right',
        dot: '.controls .dot',
        slide: '.slide',
        init: function() {
            $(this.rightArrow).click(this.nextSlide.bind(this));
            $(this.leftArrow).click(this.prevSlide.bind(this));
            $(this.dot).click(this.dotClick.bind(this));
        },
        nextSlide: function() {
            var activeSlide = $('.slide.active-slide'),
                firstSlide = $(this.slide).first(),
                lastSlide = $(this.slide).last(),
                nextUp = activeSlide.next(),
                activeDot = $(".active-dot"),
                nextDot = activeDot.next();
            activeSlide.removeClass("active-slide");
            nextUp.addClass("active-slide");
            activeDot.removeClass("active-dot");
            nextDot.addClass("active-dot");
            $(this.leftArrow).removeClass("inactive");
            if ( lastSlide.hasClass("active-slide")) {
                $(this.rightArrow).addClass("inactive");
            }

        }
    }
```

What is the proper way to use this object on multiple instances of DOM modules? In other words, what is the 'best-practice' way of using this object's functionality on two 'slide' instances in the same DOM

Comment: "best practice" is really opinion-based. It depends on how the code will be used. It appears as though you're essentially trying to make a jQuery plugin, for which there are many tutorials on the internet.

Comment: @JordanBarber are you trying to make a copy of the object and use it for differenct DOM elements? if so, you can use `var newSideSlider = Object.assign({}, SideSlider);`

Comment: @ajaiJothi I am trying to use that single object on two DOM instances (same classes) of the slider element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a constructor for your object, and then pass a container element to that constructor, so it will be acting on that DOM-slider only. Everywhere where you perform a jQuery selector to retrieve certain element(s), you should set the scope to the given container element. You can do this by providing that container as second argument to `$(..., ...)`.

The object instances are created with `new SideSlider(container)`. It could look something like this:

```
function SideSlider(container) {
    // Perform the jQuery selections with the second argument
    // so that the selection returns only elements within the container:
    this.$rightArrow = $('.controls i.right', container);
    this.$dot = $('.controls .dot', container);
    this.$slide = $('.slide', container);
    this.container = container;
    // ... etc
    // Perform init-logic immediately
    this.$rightArrow.click(this.nextSlide.bind(this));
    this.$leftArrow.click(this.prevSlide.bind(this));
    this.$dot.click(this.dotClick.bind(this));
    // ... etc
}

// Define methods on the prototype    
SideSlider.prototype.nextSlide = function() {
    var activeSlide = $('.slide.active-slide', this.container),
        firstSlide = $(this.slide, this.container).first(),
        lastSlide = $(this.slide, this.container).last(),
        nextUp = activeSlide.next(),
        activeDot = $(".active-dot", this.container),
        nextDot = activeDot.next();
    activeSlide.removeClass("active-slide");
    nextUp.addClass("active-slide");
    activeDot.removeClass("active-dot");
    nextDot.addClass("active-dot");
    $(this.leftArrow, this.container).removeClass("inactive");
    if (lastSlide.hasClass("active-slide")) {
        $(this.rightArrow, this.container).addClass("inactive");
    }
    // ... etc
};

// Create & use the two objects:
var slider1 = new SideSlider($('#slider1'));
var slider2 = new SideSlider($('#slider2'));
// ...
slider1.nextSlide();
// ...etc.
```

If you have ES6 support, use the `class` notation.

Answer (score -1):

Seeing as it looks like you are using jQuery, I would recommend looking into turning your project into a jQuery plugin. This would allow you to assign your code per use, and it's used quite commonly by developers of sliders, and other sorts of JavaScript powered widgets. The jQuery website has a great tutorial on how to accomplish this, and it can be found here:

https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/